# What are some different frameworks which can be used for SOAP

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Besides the following link, which is pro Spring, are there any other resources which show pros and cons of different Frameworks that can be used to implement SOAP in java

http://blog.arendsen.net/wp-content/TheSpringExperienceSpringWebServices.pdf

Also, I read the following on [Axis Wiki]

> Q: What is Apache Axis? What's its
>   relationship to Apache SOAP?
>
> A: As a client to a web service,
>   encoding your requests to the web
>   service, and decoding the responses
>   you get back, to and from XML would be
>   a pain (not to mention implementing
>   the logic that deals with accepting
>   requests and sending responses). The
>   same goes if you're writing the web
>   service yourself. Most folks use
>   Apache Axis to do all that for them.
>   You could write web service clients
>   and servers without something like
>   Axis, but it would be very tedious.

so Axis is only required if you are consuming a web service? is it not required  when providing a web service?

Answer (score 1):

When choosing a SOAP framework you must first decide if you are going **contract-first** (writing the WSDL file yourself) or **contract-last** (the WSDL file gets generated from code). There are multiple pros and cons of each method, but the most important are:

- Often **contract-last** style frameworks are easy to get started with. However a change in the exposed domain model may yield a change in the contract (WSDL).
- In **contract-first** you have the extra overhead of writing the WSDL yourself.

As for frameworks I have found JAX-WS ([Metro](https://metro.dev.java.net/)) to be the best for **contract-last** and Spring WS the best for **contract-first**. On a personal note I might add that I prefer **contract-first**, it really is worth the extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Axis can do both. You can also use

- [JAX-WS reference implementation](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/) (from Metro)
- [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)

Both are full-featured web-service stacks.

A separate SOAP-only component is [SAAJ](https://saaj.dev.java.net/). You can take a look at it, if you want to manually send SOAP messages.